# Declare ImageView programmatically Android

Tags: android

How can I declare some ImageViews programmatically in oncreate method ? I want to have something like this:

```
for (int i =1 ; i<=10;i++){

    ImageView image+i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image+i);

}
```

I don't know if it is possible something like this, or you have to make it imageview by imageview.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView[] imageViews = new ImageView[10];
for (int i =1 ; i<= 10; i++){
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image"+i, "id", getPackageName());
  imageViews[i - 1] = (ImageView)findViewById(id);
}
```

[getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) returns the resource's id associate to the name, the first parameter, and you could use an array to store the view's reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this method

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ImageView image+i = new ImageView(this);
    image+i.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
    image+i.setMaxHeight(20);
    image+i.setMaxWidth(20);

    // Adds the view to the layout
    layout.addView(image);
}
```

go through [this](http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137) tutorial and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14928/dynamically-create-imageview) too.